# I have a DEVINST, I need the Device Path

Tags: usb, winusb

I'm trying to open a WinUSB device that is part of a composite device. I have located the correct child device using cfgmgr32, and have its DEVINST number. In order to open it with WinUSB, I need to first call CreateFile, for which I need the Device Path.

The Device Path looks like:

`\\\\?\\usb#vid_9999&pid_0102#3555303335351909000b0#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}`

How can I obtain the Device Path?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the [get_filename_from_devinst_and_guid](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/blob/890379c54ef58de46afc60b9c3eccfe2bd66d523/src/windows/interface_windows.c) function which is part of [libusbp](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/).

The basic outline is:

1. Make sure you know the device interface GUID you are looking for.  That is the thing in brackets at the end of the filename you provided.  This usually comes from the INF file that sets up WinUSB, though it can also come from MS OS descriptors on the device.  You can find it in the registry.  You have to pack it into a Win32 API `GUID` struct.
2. Call `SetupDiGetClassDevs(guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);` to get a list of all the present (connected) devices supporting that device interface GUID.
3. Use `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` to iterate through the list until you find the item that matches the DEVINST you already found.
4. Use `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` to get the list of interfaces for that item.  There should only be one entry because you already specified the device interface GUID you are interested in.
5. Use `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` to get `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA_A` data structure.
6. The filename you are looking for is in the `DevicePath` member of that structure.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns a list of NULL-terminated Device Paths (that's what we get from `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List`)

You need to pass it the `DEVINST`, and the wanted interface `GUID`.

Since both the DEVINST and interface GUID are specified, it is highly likely that `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List` will return a single Device Path for that interface, but technically you should be prepared to get more than one result.

I used this function successfully in production code for getting the Device Interface of a USB HUB (`GUID_CLASS_USBHUB`): I used the resulting Device Path with CreateFile and opened it succesfully.

It is responsibility of the caller to `delete[]` the returned list if the function returns successfully (return code 0)

```cpp
int GetDevInstInterfaces(DEVINST dev, LPGUID interfaceGUID, wchar_t**outIfaces, ULONG* outIfacesLen)
{
    CONFIGRET cres;
    if (!outIfaces)
        return -1;
    if (!outIfacesLen)
        return -2;

    // Get System Device ID
    WCHAR sysDeviceID[256];
    cres = CM_Get_Device_ID(dev, sysDeviceID, sizeof(sysDeviceID) / sizeof(sysDeviceID[0]), 0);
    if (cres != CR_SUCCESS)
        return -11;

    // Get list size
    ULONG ifaceListSize = 0;
    cres = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_Size(&ifaceListSize, interfaceGUID, sysDeviceID, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);
    if (cres != CR_SUCCESS)
        return -12;

    // Allocate memory for the list
    wchar_t* ifaceList = new wchar_t[ifaceListSize];

    // Populate the list
    cres = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List(interfaceGUID, sysDeviceID, ifaceList, ifaceListSize, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);
    if (cres != CR_SUCCESS) {
        delete[] ifaceList;
        return -13;
    }

    // Return list
    *outIfaces = ifaceList;
    *outIfacesLen = ifaceListSize;

    return 0;
}
```